# Strange characters when reading from file in C

Tags: c

So I am just trying to learn C and have decided to program a simple calendar where you can add events etc. It is working almost perfectly however, when it tries to read from the file containing the information, the first line contains some strange characters : �<�}�U1.

Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void createCalendar(char filename[]) {
    FILE *cptr;
    cptr = fopen(filename, "w");
    char dates[177/sizeof(char)] = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
        char strtowrite[7/sizeof(char)] = "";
        sprintf(strtowrite, "%d - \n", i);
        strcat(dates, strtowrite);
    }
    fprintf(cptr, "%s", dates);
    fclose(cptr);
}

void addToDay(char filename[], int day, char event[]) {
    FILE *cptr;
    cptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char dates[177/sizeof(char) + strlen(event)/sizeof(char)];
    int i = 1;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, cptr)) != -1) {
        if (i==day) {
            char strtowrite[7/sizeof(char) + strlen(event)/sizeof(char)];
            sprintf(strtowrite, "%d - %s\n", i, event);
            strcat(dates, strtowrite);
        }
        else {
            strcat(dates, line);
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    printf("%s", dates);
    fclose(cptr);
    cptr = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(cptr, "%s", dates);
    fclose(cptr);
}

int main() {
    createCalendar("january");
    addToDay("january", 12, "event");
}
```

and the first line of output is: í¬_<89>lU1 - (in the file)

Comment: hard to say how exactly that happens. But note that you're allocating space to `dates` in `addToDay` based on the static structure and the `event` to be added. There doesn't seem to be any space for any events already in the file. Anyway, I would try hard to avoid magic numbers like that 177. A common way for handling text files would be to read the old file while writing a new version with a different name, and then rename the new file on top of the old one.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for the advice I will try that.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
char dates[177/sizeof(char) + strlen(event)/sizeof(char)] = {0};
```

in your addToDay function when declaring the dates variable. I think that you do not set the memory there, so there might be some junk in that memory location.

Comment: For further elaboration: a C-style string "ends" at the first 0 character. When you do not give value to a variable, it is not 0 by default, but some value that was there before in the memory. You need to explicitely 0 it out. So when you created the dates string, you assumed that it was empty, but the first some characters were not 0, so strcat did not see it as an empty string.

Comment: It gave me an error "variable-sized object may not be initialized", but it if you strcpy nothing into the string it solves the original problem!

Comment: Yeah, I used g++ comiler, it is compiler dependent. I would advise you to use memset to 0 out the whole memory range.